# How to delete an user including data from custom database tables

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

Is it possible to remove an user from within the back-end including all data related to this user even from custom tables?

I used the `add_action( 'delete_user', 'my_delete_user' );` hook and
also execute a delete query to delete data from a custom table (related
to that user) but only data from the **user** and **user_meta** table
is deleted, not from the custom table.

I would like to be able to delete *all* data related to an user.

Comment: Could you add the function into your question so we get an idea. Maybe there is something else in the function which holds it back from doing what it should do?

Comment: @Charles: thanks for reply i have resolved this issue by same hook.

Comment: Hey thats great, could you add an answer include working code for later reference for other users?

Comment: @Charles : see my working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hello guys!
>
> i resolved this issue by using same hook add_action( 'delete_user',
>   'my_delete_user' );
>
> here is my code

```
<?php

function my_delete_user( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_obj = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $id_user = $user_obj->ID;
    $idsss = $user_obj->user_id;


    /*Delete Data from friend table*/  
    $query_friend= $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `wp_user_friends` where `friend_id` = ".$user_obj->ID."");

    /*delete data from group*/
    $delete_group_table =$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `wp_group` where `user_id` = ".$user_obj->ID."");


}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'my_delete_user' );
?>
```

> Now it's working perfect.